# How to selectively populate state from a snapshot of one chain onto another?

Tags: storage, migration, snapshot, fork, recovery

#### Goal

To use a full snapshot at some block height of one chain and selectively pull in select parts of this state.

#### Use cases

1. Migrating state from another chain. Example:

   - A snapshot of only assets pallet on some other chain
2. Partial or complete snapshot *recovery*. Example:

   - A `sudo` state change bricked a chain, and a new one is started that wants to restart (with a new genesis) with much the same state overall, but not the corrupt parts.

#### Known tools

- [fork-off-substrate](https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate) - allows for hard forks

#### Question

**How would one perform a selective state "upload" of parts of some full chain state data?**

I think [fork-off-substrate](https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate) may have parts of the solution, but the selectivity and how to go about actually *identifying* the state to use is unclear. Also this would not *necessarily* be performed at genesis, and may need to be piece-wise for the limitations on parachains (as outlined [here in the parachain runtime upgrade How-to Guides](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/runtime-upgrades/#steps))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the code for `fork-off-substrate`, you will see that it ultimately collects a list of "module prefixes", and then queries storage using that list.

Right now it collects a list of prefixes to skip:

```javascript
/**
 * All module prefixes except those mentioned in the skippedModulesPrefix will be added to this by the script.
 * If you want to add any past module or part of a skipped module, add the prefix here manually.
 *
 * Any storage value’s hex can be logged via console.log(api.query.<module>.<call>.key([...opt params])),
 * e.g. console.log(api.query.timestamp.now.key()).
 *
 * If you want a map/doublemap key prefix, you can do it via .keyPrefix(),
 * e.g. console.log(api.query.system.account.keyPrefix()).
 *
 * For module hashing, do it via xxhashAsHex,
 * e.g. console.log(xxhashAsHex('System', 128)).
 */
let prefixes = ['0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7b99d880ec681799c0cf30e8886371da9' /* System.Account */];
const skippedModulesPrefix = ['System', 'Session', 'Babe', 'Grandpa', 'GrandpaFinality', 'FinalityTracker', 'Authorship'];
```

But your question seems to want the opposite, which is just the storage specific pallet, ignoring the rest.

For that, you just need to query the keys which start with the prefix you expect.

Starting from first principles, do something like:

```javascript
let prefix = xxhashAsHex(module.name, 128)
let allStorageKeys = api.rpc.state.getKeys(prefix);
let allStorage = api.rpc.state.queryStorageAt(allStorageKeys);
```

And then you insert these keys / values into your new chain.